# solidity-by-example.org MultiSigWallet is incomplete, right?

Tags: solidity

newbie here.

https://solidity-by-example.org/app/multi-sig-wallet/ has the main contract:

```
contract MultiSigWallet {
...
}
```

And it has this:

```
contract TestContract {
    uint public i;

    function callMe(uint j) public {
        i += j;
    }

    function getData() public pure returns (bytes memory) {
        return abi.encodeWithSignature("callMe(uint256)", 123);
    }
}
```

I remixed it and as expected it does nothing.  I wanted to confirm that yes, they have missed writing proper test code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a basic test case, it's not incomplete, you can add more functions or logic.

The main purpose of the workflow is:

1. Deploy both of the contracts.
2. Call the `getData` function and it will return the function signature that needs to be passed while creating a proposal in the multisig.
3. Create a proposal in the multisig via `submittransaction` function, passing the test contract address and the data you got from the above step,  and then execute it(depending on how many owners you have added and what is the threshold for confirmation).
4. After the proposal is executed, check the `i` variable in the test contract and you will notice that the value has been increased by `123`.

You can also try different logic within the test cases, just get a good practice of low-level calls and function signatures associated with them.

Comment: I get it, thanks.  Wow this contract tech is definitely something a little different to the dev paradigms I'm used to.  But I'm liking it muchly and hoping these patterns become second nature to me soon.

Comment: Yup it indeed is different, and fascinating :)